# In-App Purchase Payment Transaction Not Functioning

Tags: swift, xcode, app-store-connect

My app displays prompts when the user clicks a specific button. I'm want to have additional prompt packages for non-consumable in-app purchase available (click the package to purchase, then if purchased you can use that same button to toggle the package on and off).

Below is all the relevant code...

```
import UIKit
import QuartzCore
import StoreKit

class ViewController: UIViewController, SKPaymentTransactionObserver {



    let productID = "com.domain.app.purchase"


    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()

        SKPaymentQueue.default().add(self)
    }


    var packsUnlocked = false



    @IBAction func selectPack1(_ sender: UIButton) {


        if SKPaymentQueue.canMakePayments() {
            let paymentRequest = SKMutablePayment()
            paymentRequest.productIdentifier = productID
            SKPaymentQueue.default().add(paymentRequest)
            print("Initiating Transaction")
        } else {
            print("No Purchased")
        }


        if packsUnlocked == false {
            print("It's locked, ‘Pack 1’ not enabled")
        } else {
            print(“Utilize Purchase”)
            //this is where you place code to use the purchased ‘Pack 1’
        }


    }



    func paymentQueue(_ queue: SKPaymentQueue, updatedTransactions transactions: [SKPaymentTransaction]) {
        for transaction in transactions{
            if transaction.transactionState == .purchased {
                packsUnlocked = true
                print("Transaction Successful")
                } else if transaction.transactionState == .failed {
                    print("Transaction Failed")
                    }
            }

        }

}
```

However whenever I run the code and click the button all I get is the below outputs in the debugger:

```
"
Initiating Transaction
It's locked, 'Pack 1' not enabled
Transaction Failed
"
```

This is my first app and I've never set up a sandbox tester before, so I'm not sure if the code is the problem or if it's something with my App Store Connect setup.

Thank you - I've been stuck on this for wayyy too long so any help is GREATLY appreciated.

Comment: Did you check the error that comes along when the transaction is failing?

Comment: Use transaction.error https://developer.apple.com/documentation/storekit/skpaymenttransaction/1411269-error

Comment: @hariszaman i'm very new to xcode - is this not found in the debugger? I only see those three lines I mentioned above

Comment: @hariszaman thanks for the link to ```var error: Error? { get }``` but I'm very naive as to what to put in the getter statement. (also I'm assuming I'm supposed to put this after the ```print("No Purchased")```?

Comment: you can replace print("Transaction Failed") with print("Transaction Failed with error: \(transaction.error)")

Comment: @hariszaman that prints "Transaction Failed with error: (transaction.error)" directly - it's not calling any transaction.error... Am I supposed to do something with ```var error: Error? { get }``` (if so I'm having trouble figuring out what to put as the getter)

Comment: I also didn't notice this earlier but the below also appears in the debugger: ```2020-05-09 10:21:45.273131-0400 appName[#####:#########] [MC] System group container for systemgroup.com.apple.configurationprofiles path is /Users/***********/Library/Developer/CoreSimulator/Devices/AF5A1432-5CCC-4545-A1F8-0949266EDBE7/data/Containers/Shared/SystemGroup/systemgroup.com.apple.configurationprofiles
2020-05-09 10:21:45.274028-0400 appName[#####:#########] [MC] Reading from private effective user settings.``` (some of this is anonymized)

Comment: it is print("Transaction Failed with error: \\(transaction.error)"). SO somehow replaces skips one \

Comment: @hariszaman thanks this is very helpful - this tells me I have an issue logging into the iTunes Store with my simulator - I can log into my main iCloud account on it but am unable to log into the iTunes & App Store for some reason. The simluator just gives me the following error ```Could Not Sign In there was a problem connecting to the server```. I tried both my main account and my sandbox with no success. Any idea what I should be doing?

Comment: I should be able to test the IAP on my simulator, right?

Comment: No use should use a real device alongwith sandbox testing account. That error might be because you are testing it on simulator

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/213525/discussion-between-sebastian-hubard-and-hariszaman).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to test In-App Purchases on an actual device in the sandbox environment.

Here is the Apple Documentation on it, but I can guide you as well.

https://developer.apple.com/documentation/storekit/in-app_purchase/testing_in-app_purchase_transactions

Main steps are:

1. Create a sandbox or test user account in App Store Connect.
2. For iOS 12 or later — Don't sign out of the App Store; simply build and run your app from Xcode. Sandbox accounts are stored separately, and you can control your sandbox account directly on-device in Settings. (You must run on your attached device.)